# Compare 2 sheet and highlight duplicate values with 2 criteria

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, duplicates, highlight

I am new for doing Excel VBA coding. And I would like to write a simple coding which is highlight the duplicate number

If my *ShpMarkLog(test) worksheet* **SMOrder_No** = *TALLY-SHEET* **Order No**.
Then
If my *ShpMarkLog(test) worksheet* **SMNewCTNno** = *TALLY-SHEET* (**Column H8 TO AK103**)
Then Hightlight the duplicate number.
Then
If the TALLY-SHEET (Column H8 TO AK103) is blank, then put white colour with blank.

But when the system didn't follow my criteria, which is only highlight the number if the **SMOrder_No** = **Order No**.
Below is my coding.

```
Option Explicit
Sub Compare()
  Dim sh, wsh As Worksheet
        Set sh = Sheets("ShpMarkLog(test)")
        Set wsh = Sheets("TALLY-SHEET")
        
    Dim x As Long
        x = sh.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        
    Dim myRange, myRange2 As Range
        Set myRange = sh.Range("I9", "I" & x)
        Set myRange2 = sh.Range("J9", "J" & x)
    Dim p, i As Long
        p = wsh.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    
    Dim b, b2 As Integer
         
         b = 1
         For i = 8 To 103
            For b2 = 8 To 37
        
        If wsh.Cells(i, b2) = "" Then
            wsh.Cells(i, b2).Interior.ColorIndex = 2
        Else
           If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(myRange2, wsh.Cells(i, b2)) > 0 And Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(myRange, wsh.Cells(i, b)) > 0 Then
            wsh.Cells(i, b2).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
           Else
             wsh.Cells(i, b2).Interior.ColorIndex = 2
           End If
           
        End If
             
          Next b2
        Next i
    
End Sub
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wnUaq.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rWKLu.png)

I Want to make the number only highlight duplicate when the criteria is meet. May I know how should I modify the code in order to get my result.
Really really thank you.

Comment: I have attach some sample link for reference
-
Sample Picture.
https://ibb.co/FYH6FCV
https://ibb.co/DMnb8RY
-
Sample Excel Link.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hiEIEwQIobUNMj-b3E8Gr-aIeFB14DcN/edit?usp=share_link&ouid=113728469994646825003&rtpof=true&sd=true

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub HighlightDuplicates()

Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range, rng3 As Range, cell As Range

Set rng1 = Worksheets("ShpMarkLog (test)").Range("SMOrder_No")
Set rng2 = Worksheets("TALLY-SHEET").Range("A2:A103")
Set rng3 = Worksheets("TALLY-SHEET").Range("H8:AK103")

For Each cell In rng1
    If cell = rng2(cell.Row) Then
        For Each c In rng3
            If c = cell And c.Value <> "" Then
                c.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
            End If
        Next c
    End If
Next cell

For Each c In rng3
    If c.Value = "" Then
        c.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    End If
Next c

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Sir, thank you for your helping but dont know why the coding didnt work for me. 
System show Run-time error '9'.
Subscript out of range
Did I miss any step for the setting?